# Search Database doesn't work

Tags: java, android, sqlite

so I'm having a very weird problem. Basically I'm making an app that searches the database for the field 'country' and displays info based on the searched country. Now the weird part is that it only works for a few countries althrough the fields are all written the same and in the other activty with the same code it works flawlessly. What do you think the problem is?

Database.java

```
public class DBResep2 extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
final static String DB_NAME = "db_resep2";

public DBResep2(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 46);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resep2(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,luna TEXT,tara TEXT,oras TEXT,durata TEXT,facil TEXT,bani TEXT,desc TEXT,img BLOB)";
    db.execSQL(sql);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put("_id","1");
    values.put ("name","Fitness Trainer ");
    values.put ("oras","Alexandria,Egypt ");
    values.put ( "durata","1 iulie -30 septembrie ");
    values.put ( "desc"," You will have to: -Demonstrate how to carry out various exercises and routines. -Observe participants and inform them of corrective measures necessary to improve their skills. -Be self-motivated, energetic, organized and responsible. -Be a good communicator and attentive. Experience for this opportunity is required. ");
    values.put ( "country", " egipt ");
    values.put ("luna","Iulie,August,Septembrie");
    values.put("img",R.drawable.egipt);
    values.put("bani", "3000 dolari + 50% commission on private lesson ");
    db.insert("resep2", "_id", values);



@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS resep2");
    onCreate(db);

}
```

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity2 extends Activity {
    protected ListView lv;
    protected ListAdapter adapter;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    AutoCompleteTextView et_db;
    AutoCompleteTextView et_db2;


String[] arr2 = {"pakistan", "rusia", "cehia", "egipt", "turcia", "germania", "anglia", "india", "tunisia", "suedia", "cehia"};

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    db = (new DBResep2(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    et_db = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et);
    et_db2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et2);




    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM resep2 ORDER BY name ASC", null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.isi_lv2, cursor,
                new String[] { "name", "oras" , "img" }, new int[] {
                R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvOras, R.id.imV });
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                detail(position);

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arr);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
    AutoCompleteTextView actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et2);
    actv.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
    actv.setAdapter(adapter);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, arr2);
    //Getting the instance of AutoCompleteTextView
    AutoCompleteTextView actv2 = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et);
    actv2.setThreshold(1);//will start working from first character
    actv2.setAdapter(adapter2);//setting the adapter data into the AutoCompleteTextView
}
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void search_db(View v) {
    String edit_db = et_db.getText().toString();
    if (!edit_db.equals("")) {
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM resep2 WHERE country LIKE ?",
                    new String[] { "%" + edit_db + "%" });
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.isi_lv2,
                    cursor,
                    new String[] { "name", "oras", "img" },
                    new int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvOras, R.id.imV });
            if (adapter.getCount() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        this,
                        "Nu am putut gasi niciun proiect in " + edit_db
                                + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        try {
            cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM resep2 ORDER BY name ASC",
                    null);
            adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    R.layout.isi_lv2,
                    cursor,
                    new String[] { "name", "oras", "img" },
                    new int[] { R.id.tv_name, R.id.tvOras, R.id.imV });
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so which countries DOES this work for?

Comment: Out of 14 countries, it only works for pakistan and germany/germania

Comment: **resep2** doesn't appear to have a column named **country** according to _`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS resep2(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT,luna TEXT,tara TEXT,oras TEXT,durata TEXT,facil TEXT,bani TEXT,desc TEXT,img BLOB)"`_

Comment: Sorry it's there,but i forgot to translate it. It's tara=country

Comment: I can't see anything. If in this situation I'd first look to see whether the issue is due to the SELECT or further on. I'd add a Toast, Log or breakpoint immediately after the query and look at the number of rows returned.